# getSingleton is undefined

Tags: android, bluetooth, nxt

im trying to make bluetooth connection from android to NXT LeJos Droid. It works fine in other project, but when i need it for another project , it doesnt want to resolved the getSingleton()

```
public void onConnectionClicked(View view) {
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked(); 


    // turning it on just sets the flag 
    if(on) {
        conn = MainActivity.connect(CASE_TYPE.LEGO_LCP);
        NXTCommand.getSingleton().setNXTComm(conn.getNXTComm());
        NXTInfo info = conn.getNXTInfo();
        if (info.connectionState== NXTConnectionState.LCP_CONNECTED)
        {
            isConnected = true;

        }

    }

    // turning it off captures one more frame and starts processing 
    if(!on) {

         try {
                conn.getNXTComm().close();
            } catch (Exception e) {} finally {

                conn = null;
            }

    }
}
```

it said unresolved

i tried to fix it by checking the permission and library. I even change attached source inside lejos.nxt.remote.NXTCommand to the path where pccomm.jar located , but it doesnt work. I'd tried clean project .

is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: check your pccomm.jar, with JD-GUI

Comment: pccomm.jar is fine, because i also use the same jar for another project and it works well